# How to deal with the black area beyond the SKView() (In Swift Playground)

Tags: swift, swiftui, sprite-kit

I'm trying to use SpriteKit+SwiftUI in my work running in Swift Playground. Here are some of my codes

```
struct SwiftUI: View {
    var body: some View {
         Test() 
    }
}
struct Test: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> SKView {
        let sceneView = SKView()
        let gameScene = GameScene()
        gameScene.size = CGSize(width: 500, height: 600)
        gameScene.scaleMode = .aspectFit
        sceneView.presentScene(gameScene)
        return sceneView
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: SKView, context: Context) {
    }
}
```

It runs well, but always have this awful **Black area** beyond my SKView like the image below.
[Black area in the View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKGys.png).
I have tried to change the `sceneView.backgroundcolor`,or change the `gameScene.size` and `sceneView.size` but those just didn't work.  
Thanks so much if you can give me some advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the call to `Test()` also needs to have an explicit frame size set. Otherwise, the `Test` view takes up the entire available screen space, while the sceneView only takes up a portion of this space.

The example below is the same one that you posted, with an explicit frame set on `Test()` (and a dummy `GameScene`). This works in the playground, where the result is just a purple square with no black area beyond the view:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import SpriteKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let width: CGFloat = 500
let height: CGFloat = 500

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
         Test()
            .frame(width: width, height: height)
    }
}
struct Test: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> SKView {
        let sceneView = SKView()
        let gameScene = GameScene()
        gameScene.size = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
        gameScene.scaleMode = .aspectFit
        sceneView.presentScene(gameScene)
        return sceneView
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: SKView, context: Context) {
    }
}

class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        let node = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
        node.fillColor = .purple
        addChild(node)
    }
}


PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```